# NEXT JS - How to prevent layout get re-mounted?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Trying next with layout pattern:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/layout-component

And the problem is that Layout component get remounted on every page change. I need to use layout component as a Container so it'll fetch data from server on every mount. How can I prevent layout to get re-mounted? Or am I missing something there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you put your `Layout` component inside page component it will be re-remounted on page navigation (page switch).

You can wrap your page component with your `Layout` component inside `_app.js`, it should prevent it from re-mounting.

Something like this:

```js
// _app.js
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

class MyApp extends App {
 static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
    return {
      ...appProps,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Layout />
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: What if I need to fetch data from server on ComponentDidMount in layout component? Use it like Container. I also need multiple containers in my project. Is it possible with Next?

Comment: You can store "global" data in there, and expose (via context) an api for page components

Comment: So layout rerendering is necessary evil? Nothing can be done about it?

Comment: If it is inside a page, and you are navigating out -> new page must be mounted, therefore your layout will be remounted.

Comment: And where's no way to keep component state (layout's) while changing url and adding/removing child components? Like it could be done in react-router.

Comment: Where api call is have to placed inside a component so it won't be called on every url change even though the component stays on both pages?

Comment: There is a way, by using "something" (context) that will hold the state at the `_app` and your layout will use this context api to fetch (or use cached data)

Answer (score 24):

This helped me for persistent layouts. The author puts together a function that wraps your page components in your Layout component and then passes that fetch function to your _app.js. This way the _app.js is actually the components that renders the Layout but you get to specify which pages use which layout (in case you have multiple layouts).

So you have the flexibility of having multiple layouts throughout your site but those pages that share the same layout will actually share the same layout component and it will not have to be remounted on navigation.

Here is the link to the full article
[Persistent Layout Patterns in Next.js](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/)

Here are the important code snippets. A page and then _app.js

```js
// /pages/account-settings/basic-information.js
import SiteLayout from '../../components/SiteLayout'
import AccountSettingsLayout from '../../components/AccountSettingsLayout'

const AccountSettingsBasicInformation = () => (
  <div>{/* ... */}</div>
)

AccountSettingsBasicInformation.getLayout = page => (
  <SiteLayout>
    <AccountSettingsLayout>{page}</AccountSettingsLayout>
  </SiteLayout>
)

export default AccountSettingsBasicInformation
```

```js
// /pages/_app.js
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, router } = this.props

    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => page)

    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps}></Component>)
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Great answer, very clever!

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure you replace all the `<a href=""></a>` to `<Link href=""></Link>`, notice that only have change the Html tag to link.

I struggled because with this for many days, although I was doing everything else correctly, these `<a>` tags were the culprit that was causing the `_app.js` remount on page change

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is the topic `Layout` being mounted again and again, the root cause of this problem is that you have some data loaded in some child component which is getting fetched again and again.

After some fooling around, I found none of these problem is actually what Next.Js or SWR solves. The question, back to square one, is how to streamline a single copy of data to some child component.

#### Context

Use `context` as a example.

Config.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
export default createContext({})
```

_App.js

```
import Config from '../Config'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Config.Provider value={{ user: { name: 'John' }}}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Config.Provider>
  )
}
```

Avatar.js

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import Config from '../Config'

function Avatar() {
  const { user } = useContext(Config)
  return (
    <span>
      {user.name}
    </span>
  )
}

export default Avatar
```

No matter how you mount and dismount, you won't end up with re-render, as long as the `_app` doesn't.

#### Writable

The above example is only dealing with readable. If it's writable, you can try to pass a state into context. `setUser` will take care the set in consumer.

```
  <Provider value={useState({})} />
```

```
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(Config)
```

`setUser` is "cached" and won't be updated. So we can use this function to reset the user anytime in child consumer.

---

There're other ways, ex. React Recoil. But more or less you are dealing with a state management system to send a copy (either value or function) to somewhere else without touching other nodes. I'll leave this as an answer, since even we solved Layout issue, this problem won't disappear. And if we solve this problem, we don't need to deal with Layout at all.