# Fixed side menu on an specific Next.js route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm starting a new project and I would like to always have a top nav and only in a specific route have a sidebar where I can click and the content will change.

- The top nav should always be visible if I am in site.com or site.com/*/**
- If I go to site.com/posts I want to see a sidebar with all the posts title
- If I click a post on the left it will redirect to site.com/posts/1 and only the right side should change

I'm having trouble with the second and third bullet. My pages path is `pages/posts/index.js` and `pages/posts/[id].js` but how can I declare only one file and avoid duplicating code?

I tried `pages/posts/[[...slug]].js` but I'm seeing this error: `Error: Optional catch-all routes are currently experimental and cannot be used by default ("/posts/[[...slug]]")`

I'm looking for examples but so far I couldn't do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/ This should solve the issue

Comment: @Mati - Did you find a solution? I'm having a hard time figuring out where to enable the `optionalCatchAll` experimental feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NEXT JS - How to prevent layout get re-mounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519286/next-js-how-to-prevent-layout-get-re-mounted)

Answer (score 4):

### Update: Next.js now recommends to use function getLayout()

[New Documentation ✨](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

---

### Create a file: /layouts/RequiredLayout.js

```js
const RequiredLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};

export default RequiredLayout;
```

### Then edit _app.js

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const Layout = Component.Layout || EmptyLayout;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

const EmptyLayout = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

export default MyApp;
```

Now whenever you require to use this layout, then add only a single line at the end

```js
NameOfComponent.Layout = RequiredLayout;
```

### For in your case: In **pages/posts/[id].js**

```js
import React from 'react'

const ID = () => {
  return(
    <>
      <p>page with id details</p>
    </>
  )
}

export deafult ID;

ID.Layout = RequiredLayout //responsible for layout
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable this experimental option by having my `next.config.js` look like this (I'm using Next v9.4.4):

```js
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    optionalCatchAll: true,
  },
};
```