# React Mapbox persist map between routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mapbox

Recently, I've been trying to implement a MapBox Map that is shared between multiple routes on my NextJS page, but when navigating for example from `foo.com` to `foo.com/bar` using `router.push("/${id}", undefined, { shallow: true });`(for testing purposes, these routes are identical and share the same `<Map/>` component), the map re-renders resulting in an annoying tile-re-render that takes around 2 seconds.

My question is, is there a way to persist the `<Map/>` component between routes without the need of re-rendering it? For libraries, I've tried using both `mapbox-gl` and `react-mapbox-gl`, for framework I'm using React and NextJS.

Here is my `<Map/>` component implementation

```js
const MapBox = ReactMapboxGl({
    accessToken: "private stuff",
});

export const Map = () => {
    return (
        <MapBox
            style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
            containerStyle={{
                height: "100vh",
                width: "100vw",
            }}
        ></MapBox>
    );
};
```

And here is my routing setup:

```
my-project/
├─ pages/
│  ├─ [id]/
│  │  ├─ index.tsx < Contains the <Map/> component
│  ├─ index.tsx < Contains the <Map/> component
│  ├─ _app.tsx
```

Comment: Because the map is located inside each page, it will always re-mount when navigating between pages. If you want to map to be persistent, move it to a layout component outside the page components as described in [NEXT JS - How to prevent layout get re-mounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519286/next-js-how-to-prevent-layout-get-re-mounted).