# how to keep state of sidebar same in every page in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state

I want to keep the same state of the sidebar when i navigate between pages , how do i achive that ?

*code in _app.js*

```
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const open = useState(false);
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState({});

  const headerVisibility = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <HeaderContext.Provider value={headerVisibility}>
        <NavigationBar open={open} />
        <Content open={open}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Content>
      </HeaderContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
// console.clear();
export default MyApp;
```

this is how i am fetching data in navigation/sidebar

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const rawData = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/data");
    const jsonData = await abc.json();

    setData((prevState) => jsonData);
    setnavData((prevState) => jsonData);

  
  }, []);
```

Comment: why not use the router?

Comment: could you elaborate on what 'setData' and 'setnavData' is? Are those changing component state or the state within _app? You need to pass the "setState" function of the _app state as the 'value' prop of your Context Provider and then access it within the components via the "useContext" hook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NEXT JS - How to prevent layout get re-mounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519286/next-js-how-to-prevent-layout-get-re-mounted)