# Is there a way in Next.js to programmatically replace all <a> tags in nested components to avoid entire page reloads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We have to use a React component lib from our client which provides various layout components, including Header/Footer stuff and Navigation menus. In those, only the `href` string value of navigation items can be passed, no ReactNode or anything that would allow render manipulation.

When setting up NextJS routing, we noticed that pages called with those navigation menus cause the entire application to remount; even the stuff inside `_app.tsx`, which should remain mounted across routes, gets reinitialized.

My search led me to this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70617373/3265879) talking about how `<a href="">` set directly without using `Link` from NextJS router package causes this behavior:
This is exactly what's happening with our project; I verified by rendering an additional -based navigation in parallel, which makes everything work as it should.

Since we have no access to the library source code and requesting a change would probably take a while (if they'd even do it...), my question is:
Is there ANY way to manipulate those components from the outside to replace all instances of `<a>` with a `<Link>` component?

Or alternatively (probably more likely), is there a way to identify/catch all `<a href="">` calls within a NextJS application that did NOT originate from a `<Link>` component and then trigger the caught route change manually in the router so it would behave as if `<Link>` was clicked?

Or any other idea how this can be solved?

(We are using NextJS for the first time, we only used React by itself until now, so our knowledge of NextJS internal stuff is still limited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot control those `a` coming from the outside, you can overwrite them globally, in your `_app.js` component, like so:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const useNextNavigationSystem = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      router.push(e.currentTarget.href);
    };

    const aLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    aLinks.forEach((aLink) => {
      aLink.addEventListener("click", useNextNavigationSystem);
    });

    // clean up before the component is destroyed
    return () => {
      aLinks.forEach((aLink) => {
        aLink.removeEventListener("click", useNextNavigationSystem);
      });
    };
  }, [router]);
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much :) Good to know it can be that simple.